# How to reshape and summarise categorical data from long to wide?

Tags: r, database, reshape, categorical-data

My data base is like this one:

```
db <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var2 = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
           var3 = c("G", "H", "G", "G", "K"))
db

  var1 var2 var3
    A    X    G
    B    X    H
    C    Y    G
    D    Y    G
    E    Y    K
```

I'd like to reshape based in var2 and count the occurrences of var3 to get this result:

```
  var2 var3.G var3.H var3.K
    X    1      1      0
    Y    2      0      1
```

I have tried the cast and the reshape functions with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xtabs function is reasonably simple to use. The only cognitive jump is to realize that there is no LHS unless you want to do summation of a third variable:

```
> xtabs( ~var2+var3, data=db)
    var3
var2 G H K
   X 1 1 0
   Y 2 0 1
```

You don't want to do `as.data.frame` on this since it will convert to long form but you can use `as.data.frame.matrix` on it, since an R-'table' inherits from the 'matrix' class.

Comment: More elegant solution! I will just wait some time to check it.

Comment: I don't need the check and RStudent had a somewhat more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
tbl <- data.frame( var2 = db[,2], var3 = paste("var3", db[,3], sep = "."))
table(tbl)
    var3
var2 var3.G var3.H var3.K
   X      1      1      0
   Y      2      0      1
```

Comment: Very smart solution! I will just add: `tbl <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(tbl))`.

Comment: Yes... the first colum became rownames

Answer (score 2):

One more option. Using the super useful [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package:

```
library(data.table)

db <- data.table(var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), var2 = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
           var3 = c("G", "H", "G", "G", "K"))

dcast.data.table(db, var2 ~ var3, fun = length, value.var= 'var3')
   var2 G H K
1:    X 1 1 0
2:    Y 2 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way go about it:

You can use a combination of t() and table().

```
db <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                 var2 = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
                 var3 = c("G", "H", "G", "G", "K"))
db

t(table(db$var3,db$var2))
```